# Build debian package on ROS2 without recompiling

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build deb files from my private packages on private repos. Right now, I could loop through each package and build my debs, following this simple script:

```
mkdir artifacts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip fakeroot dpkg-dev debhelper dh-python
pip install bloom
. /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
# Already compiled with colcon build
. /root/windrose/install/setup.bash

echo "yaml file:///custom.yaml galactic" >> /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
rosdep update

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for x in $(colcon list -t --paths); do
    if [[ $(echo $x | awk '{print $3}') == *"ros.ament"* ]]; then
        cd $(echo $x | awk '{print $2}')
        bloom-generate rosdebian
        fakeroot debian/rules binary
        cd $OLDPWD
        deb_location=$(find ~/windrose/src/windrose -name "*.deb")
        dpkg -i $deb_location
        mv $deb_location artifacts
    fi
done

unset OLDIFS
unset IFS
```

My issues:

- fakeroot debian/rules binary recompiles the package while I already did it with colcon build. Is there a way to avoid this and use the colcon build workspace?
- fakeroot debian/rules binary also runs tests, I'd like to disable them with -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF for example, is it possible?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398639/build-debian-package-on-ros2-without-recompiling/) by [Dben](https://answers.ros.org/users/22364/dben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt that this is possible because when you are generating Debian files you are doing this in a separate (`fakeroot`) environment. Otherwise, you can end up with broken links inside binaries.

On the other hand, this process is simple to automate, so it shouldn't be actually an issue.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1